# Stored Procedure getting executed 32 times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran into this issue and I'm not sure what's causing it. My professor is equally puzzled.

```
 create procedure getName
    @AuthorNum  decimal(2,0)
as
begin
    select AUTHOR_LAST 'Last Name', AUTHOR_FIRST 'First Name' 
    from AUTHOR 
    where AUTHOR_NUM = @AuthorNum
end
go

execute getName 9
```

This should return `Collins Bradley`. Instead it executes 32 times. The first time returns the expected result, but each of the other 31 times returns the entry for the 2nd entry in the table (`Soloratoff Paul` if you're interested)

Any clue why it executes the maximum number of times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by looking at the entry in the Stored Procedures folder.

Apparently `execute getName 2` had been snuck in there when I executed the creation. I forgot to put a `go` between my create block and the execute block. That's what happens when you execute just pieces of a query...

Comment: Congrats that you found a solution yourself! Just one hint: If you do nothing else than reading data, a stored procedure is not the best place to do this. You should prefer an *inline* table valued function (without `BEGIN ...END`)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. This was an answer to an assignment so the question specifically asked for this

Comment: One other tip, when call a SP with the execute, use named parameters.  That way, if the order of the parameters changes in the future, no code will break.